# Stripe One time payment with trial period + Renewal (Subscription) payment

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

We offer a product that enables customers to self-onboard, featuring the following payment structure:

1. During onboarding, customers are required to make an initial payment of USD 1500, inclusive of a 15-day trial period. After the trial, customers have access to the portal for a year.
2. Following the initial year, customers will incur a recurring annual charge of USD 1000.

I encountered an issue with Stripe while trying the 'Phase' option during subscription creation. It fails, stating that no recurring payment is configured, although I created the second product as a recurring payment.

I tried the following code to generate the checkout session for a user, but it isn't working as expected.

```
public async Task<string> GetStripeSessionLink()
    {
        StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "<<API_KEY>>";
        var options = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionCreateOptions
        {
            PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string>() { "card" },
            SubscriptionData = new SessionSubscriptionDataOptions
            {
                TrialSettings = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionSubscriptionDataTrialSettingsOptions
                {
                    EndBehavior = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionSubscriptionDataTrialSettingsEndBehaviorOptions
                    {
                        MissingPaymentMethod = "cancel",
                    },
                },
                TrialPeriodDays = 1,
            },
            LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions> { new SessionLineItemOptions
            {
                Price = "price_1O9j4cSERQQSOAmawe834DECNSRnKmYzDsX",
                Quantity = 1,
            },
            new SessionLineItemOptions {
                Price = "price_1OAYkVSERQQSOA454SfgrVs44mR1TpitOov",
                Quantity = 1
            },
            },
            Mode = "subscription",
            SuccessUrl = "http://localhost:4300/dashboard",
            CancelUrl = "http://localhost:4300/register/cancel",
            AllowPromotionCodes = true,
            CustomerEmail = "abcxyz@gmail.com",
        };
        var service = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionService();
        var session = service.Create(options);
        return session.Url;
    }
```

How can I properly configure Stripe for these specific payment options?

Do I need to create a subscription first and then after trial, convert the subscription to a subscription schedule?

Or

Create a subscription for Initial payment and onboard the customer. Once the trial period ends, charge the customer with USD 1500 and cancel the current subscription and enroll the customer into recurring annual payment subscription?

Comment: Please share all relevant code and specific error messages in order for folks to be able to help you.

Comment: @bismarck added the additional code.

Answer (score 0):

--Updated--

What you would need is a one-time Price and yearly Price on your Checkout Session `line_items`:
-The one-time Price will be billed on day one.
-The yearly Price will be billed on trial-end.

When the customer completes the Checkout form, you'll get an event trigger (`checkout.session.completed`), which includes a `subscription`.

You'll need to attach a Subscription Schedule to this Subscription, then update that Schedule to include a new phase that changes the price after one iteration.

Hope you'll forgive me using Python here, I'm not familiar with C#.

```
schedule = stripe.SubscriptionSchedule.create(
        from_subscription='{{subscription_id}}'
        )
# You now have a Schedule object parented to your Subscription

stripe.SubscriptionSchedule.modify(
        schedule['id'],
        phases=[
            {
            'start_date':schedule['phases'][0]['start_date'],
            'iterations':1,
            'items':[{
                'price':schedule['phases'][0]['items'][0]['price'],
                'quantity':schedule['phases'][0]['items'][0]['quantity']
            }],
        },
            {
                'iterations':1,
                'proration_behavior':'none',
                'items':[{
                    'price':'{new-price}',
                    'quantity':'{new-quantity}'
                }]
            },
        ]
)
```

There isn't a way to handle the second change from the Checkout Session, hence the use of this Susbcription Schedule.

Don't forget to set `proration_behavior='none'` on your phase, because the phase update is actually going to trigger out of step for the billing period, because of the reset that will trigger with the trial-end.

Comment: Please see the updated Question. I need to create a checkout session url as mentioned

Comment: Edited my answer