# update subscription after trial ends stripe api

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I have a situation where I have to switch price ID once the trial has ended in stripe api.

So far I tried to create a schedule but it creates a new subscription. This is my code below.

```
  $data = [
     'customer' => $stripeCustomer->id,
      'items' => [
       ['price' => $priceId],
     ],
     'collection_method' => 'charge_automatically',
      'cancel_at' => Carbon::now()->addYears(1)->timestamp,
     'description' => $description,
   ];
   $subscription = $this->stripe->subscriptions->create($data);
    $schedule = $this->stripe->subscriptionSchedules->create([
                        'from_subscription' => $subscription->id,
                        //'customer' => $stripeCustomer->id,
                        //'start_date' => Carbon::now()->addYears(1)->timestamp,
                        'start_date' => Carbon::now()->addSeconds(60)->timestamp,
                        'end_behavior' => 'release',
                        'phases' => [
                            [
                                'items' => [
                                    [
                                        'price' => $product['product']->metadata->schedule_price,
                                        'quantity' => 1,
                                    ],
                                ],
                                //'end_date' => Carbon::now()->addYears(20)->timestamp,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ]);c
```

Comment: Does the code I provided here helps ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77454708/stripe-one-time-payment-with-trial-period-renewal-subscription-payment

Comment: @Lucky2501 It sounds like same but it's really difficult to understand whats going on,.

Comment: Fair. Anyway I wouldn't suggest using `subscription->create()` if you're just going to use a Subscription Schedule. Just use a Subscription Schedule to create the Subscription. Like this: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#upgrading-subscriptions (it's basically a simpler version of that code)

Comment: For instance, I don't see the use in using the `cancel_at` param in the `Subscription->create()`, when you can use `end_behavior=cancel` in your Subscription Schedule so that it auto-cancels after all phase iterations.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `from_subscription` parameter when creating a Subscription Schedule, you're blocked from using most other parameters.

You'll want to break up your current Subscription Schedule creation request into two separate requests. The first one should only create the Subscription Schedule, using the `from_subscription` parameter. Once the Subscription Schedule has been created you can make another request to update it and make your desired changes.

Source: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_schedules/create#create_subscription_schedule-from_subscription